# Send tombstone to compacted topic with kafkaTemplate

Tags: spring-kafka, nullable

I have a compacted topic and I try to send null value (tombstone) with kafkaTemplate, but getting an exception

> Unsupported Avro type. Supported types are null, Boolean, Integer, Long, Float, Double, String, byte[] and IndexedRecord

Here is my sending call

```
kafkaTemplate.send(topic, GenericMessage<KafkaNull>(KafkaNull.INSTANCE))
```

and part of kafkaTemplate configuration

```
@Bean
fun kafkaTemplate(producerFactory: ProducerFactory<String, Any>) =
KafkaTemplate(producerFactory)
```

According to [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#tombstones) I have to use KafkaNull as a null-value.
How to send it without any exceptions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with producer factory configuration.
There was

```
ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG to KafkaAvroSerializer::class.java
```

and I added new producer factory with

```
ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG to StringSerializer::class.java
```

so there is tombstone sending code

```
stringKafkaTemplate.send(internalTopic, key, null)
```